# I am stuck on changing the Report Filter in an OLAP cube in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, olap

I have a field called "Markup Range" which is set as a Report Filter in an OLAP cube. I regularly filter out the value "0.00" from it in multiple tables, so was thinking of automating this task.

But the problem is that when I record a macro filtering out 0, to get an idea as to how to approach the task, I get a huge number of "AddPageItem" statements. One for each item in "Markup Range". Totalling in thousands. I havent been able to find an alternative to "AddPageItem" for this particular purpose.

I have tried "HiddenItemsList" as well. Doesnt work. Here is a sample out of those "AddPageItems" statements:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("[Markup Range]")
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.01]", True
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.02]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.03]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.04]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.05]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.06]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.07]"
        .AddPageItem "[Markup Range].[All Markup Range].[.08]"
```

And the list goes on till 99.99. Even though the task at hand is an extremely simple one, I cant seem to find any other way to do it.

Any kind of help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what the range "Markup Range" would look like? So as to be able to formulate an answer to your question...

Comment: its a range of almost a thousand numbers starting from 0.00 to 99.99. it is placed in the report filter of the cubes/pivot tables.